# How to Identify malicious code inside lua scripts that may be obfuscated/encrypted

Tags: encryption, lua, obfuscation

I am part of a popular forum that is all about sharing/selling Lua scripts, some are open source, some are not.

I would like to know if there is an automated way of identifying if a certain Lua script contains malicious code, for example : os.execute('format C:') , or just any os.execute command.

Because, even if we require the user to provide the moderators with a open source copy of his script, how can we be sure if it's the same? or he changes the link to his script.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Lua is a capable programming language and users run it outside of sandboxes. You could provide a sandbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the scripts inside a [sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security)) and only allow for the safe commands to be executed. For example, disable `os.execute`. See [Lua SandBoxes](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SandBoxes) wiki page for Lua-specific details.

If you need to allow calls like `os.execute`, but need to filter out *some* calls, then there is probably not much chance to secure it based on code review. What if the code includes something like `os.execute('for'..'mat C'..string.char(58))`? You can't even detect that it's 'format C:' without some code execution.